# adding data from MariaDB to PostgreSQL by trigger

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, triggers, mariadb

I need to make trigger on mariaDB which will insert new data to the postgresql database on another server. Can I do this with by simply execute some query on the remote postgresql server from mariadb? In postgresql it can be done with

```
perform *  from dblink('dbname=name port=5432 user=username password=password hostaddr=host_adress',query)alias(col text);
```

but I didn't understand how can I make it with mariadb.

Comment: MySQL/MariaDB cannot invoke things outside of itself.